# Passing variable using localStorage to loaded page from iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have two pages. The parent page has an iframe that loads a page where I need to pass a variable to set the number of results in an array from xml. Below is the code for both pages. I am trying to use localStorage to pass the var to define the number of articles returned in the parse.

code on main page

```js
<script>
   localStorage.removeItem('ccm');
       localStorage.setItem('ccm','5');
          shoimg = localStorage.getItem('ccm');
</script>
```

```html
<iframe
     src="https://www.page.html" title="Articles" width="500" height="800"align="center">
</iframe>
```

Code on second page

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

       xmlhttp.open("GET","sample3.xml",false);
           xmlhttp.send(null);
               xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
                     document.write("<table id='content' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>");

                var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");                
                      for (i=0;i < shoimg;i++)
  
{       
     document.write("<tr><td><a target='_blank'href='"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"'><img src='"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"'/><h2>"+x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p></a></td></tr>");
  }

 document.write("</table>");

</script>
```

Comment: Research "passing data to iframe" instead. As this is more general, and will result in more info.

Comment: Couldn't you just set it as a url param on the iframe src?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error I found in your code-

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
```

In this line, you are trying to get an `<item>` tag in HTML page, whereas there is no
such valid element uptil now (HTML5). Try to replace this with something else that fits your needs.

Thank you!

Comment: The code you referenced is not a problem, it is part of the parse of an xml page that is being loaded. The global variable is being set by code in the iframe that is loading the second page. two different functions

Comment: Oh, my bad. Didn't see that it was an xml parsed doc...